# Invalid JSON when adding html to key

Tags: json

I need to add HTML to JSON:

```
{
    "refined_summary_t": "<ol><li> The FDA revised its guidance document which was originally released in June,
    to give device sponsors additional time in responding to FDA’ s requests
    for additional information
    for device applications that are on hold. < /lo> <
    li > At the onset of the pandemic,
    FDA realized that device makers were faced with unprecedented challenges related to supply chain issues,
    human resources,
    etc.,
    while on the other hand,
    the FDA saw a surge in EUA activities which required shifting of staff resources at the FDA.During this time,
    the FDA released a guidance document to extend the timeline
    for responding to the FDA’ s requests
    for submissions / applications that were put on hold.The originally released guidance document provided a sigh of relief to device sponsors by allowing an additional 90 day period beyond the response date initially assigned. < /li> <
    li > Under the revision of the same guidance document,
    the FDA provides an additional 180 days
    for submission of responses to the FDA’ s requests before they are withdrawn.For premarket approval(PMA) applications and humanitarian device exemption(HDE) applications,
    FDA typically allows 360 days
    for applicants to submit a complete response to a major deficiency letter and 180 days
    for responses to additional information letters
    for 510(k) s and de novo requests. < /li> <
    li > This policy applies to the submission types listed below,
    which are placed on hold pending additional information or complete response to a major deficiency
    for PMA or HDE.These submission types do not require the submission of an extension request by the sponsor:
        <
        ol >
        <
        li > Pre - market application < /li> <
    li > Humanitarian Device Exemption < /li> <
    li > De Novo applications < /li> <
    li > 510(k) < /li> < /
    ol > <
    /li>

    <
    li > FDA also mentioned in the guidance document that due to the pandemic and emergency authorization services taking a priority in its operations,
    it is not able to keep up with the current level of performance associated with the timelines and plans on communicating any delays directly with the sponsor. < /li>

    <
    /ol>"

}
```

But it gives this error

```
Error: Parse error on line 2:
...refined_summary_t": "<ol><li> The FDA re
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

I tried a simple html like this one and it was working fine:

```
"refined_summary_t": "<ol><li> first list</li><li> Second</li></ol>"
```

This one works fine but the other doesn't. They seem the same. Where does it go wrong?

Comment: *How* are you adding HTML to JSON? By opening a text editor and copypasting it in? That won't work.

Comment: @Tomalak I copy paste the text only. Add tags around it myself

Comment: Yeah, as I said, that won't work. You can't simply paste any text into JSON and expect that it doesn't break.

Comment: @Tomalak what's the work around. I have around 600 bulleted list in a word document I can't write it down myself

Comment: The work around is that you need to generate JSON from a data structure in a programming language, using a JSON serializer, not with a text editor and copy/paste and finger-crossing. Which tool or programming language works for you depends on what you have available and what your preferences/skills are.